# Django pagination: redirect to specific page after edit (FBV)

Tags: django, django-views

I'm listing 300 of customers records using a pagination in Django. Each page contains 20 records. Suppose i'm on page 7 and selected a record to edit . After editing the record, successful url to redirect list view(which is first page). So I want , if I edit in `?page=7`, when the edit in done by customer `id` it will come back to `?page=7`.

**Here** is my `customer_list` view in `view.py`:

```
def customer_list(request):
    posts_list = Customer.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        posts_list = Customer.objects.filter(
            Q(invoice__addresses__contact_number__icontains=query) |
            Q(invoice__addresses__address__icontains=query) |
            Q(shipping_method__icontains=query) 
        ).distinct()
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(posts_list, 20)  # 20 posts per page
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'page': page
    }
    return render(request, "customers/customer_list.html", context)
```

**Here** is `update_customer_list` view in `view.py`:

```
def update_customer_list(request, id):
    """
       Here, update single customer id form customer table
       :param request:
       :param id:
       :return:
       """
    obj = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=id)
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Customer successfully Updated')
        return redirect('customer_list')
    return render(request, 'customers/customerUpdateForm.html', {'form': form})
```

**Here** is `update_customer_list` url in `urls.py`:

```
path('update_customer_list/<int:id>/', views.update_customer_list, name='update_customer_list'),
```

I am waiting for someones help and help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: pass the page paramater to the edit view then redirect to page list with query parameter the page parameter

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis thanks for your reply .. I got your point .. Can you show an example how to implement it ..?? Actually I thought it first (according to your ans) but confused about the implementation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pass the page parameter to the url and inside function you have:

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse_lazy
def update_customer_list(request, id):
"""
   Here, update single customer id form customer table
   :param request:
   :param id:
   :return:
   """
page = request.GET.get("page") 
obj = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=id)
form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Customer successfully Updated')
    url = reverse_lazy("customer_list") + "?page=" + page
    return redirect(url)
return render(request, 'customers/customerUpdateForm.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I tried .. but `page = request.GET.get("page")` gives `None` .. Can you tell why ??

Comment: you have to pass the page parameter to the link for the edit view  as request get paramater

Comment: my edit page url in browser is : `http://localhost:8000/update_customer_list/18/`

Comment: http://localhost:8000/update_customer_list/18/?page=1  the page as get parameter

Comment: still can't able to figure it out :(

Comment: http://localhost:8000/update_customer_list/20/?page=None I got this

Comment: read this article for django pagination https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html